# How to do numerical transformation with data frames

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames. They both have same number of rows and the column `name` is identical. Here is an example

df1

```
           name       value
0    000001.XSHE      50000
1    000002.XSHE     100000
2    000009.XSHE      75000
```

df2

```
            name      count
0    000001.XSHE         20
1    000002.XSHE        100
2    000009.XSHE         50
```

Now I want to create a new data frame, that the third column is the result of `value / count`

Expected df3

```
            name     result
0    000001.XSHE       2500
1    000002.XSHE       1000
2    000009.XSHE       1500
```

Eventually I guess `DataFrame.apply` is the right function to do the transformation, but I don't know what is the most efficient way to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas.DataFrame.merge) the 2 dfs then the operation is simple division:

```
In [29]:
df2 = df.merge(df1)
df2['result'] = df2['value']/df2['count']
df2

Out[29]:
          name   value  count  result
0  000001.XSHE   50000     20  2500.0
1  000002.XSHE  100000    100  1000.0
2  000009.XSHE   75000     50  1500.0
```

The merge will match on common columns where the values agree in both dfs